# Is there any PHP script to sell images and videos

Tags: php, e-commerce

I know there are open source solutions like OSCommerce in php to sell stuff with paypal integration. Now I'd need something to sell Images (or files in general). Requirements:

- Paypal integration (must)
- Be able to provide download links in a secure way (so that they expire after a certain amount of time)
- Purchase must be instant, so that after you pay, you get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned OSCommerce, there is also ZenCart. All of these have the capability to include digital files. Choose the payment option of your choice such as paypal, go into the backend of the software and add your products with an accurate thumbnail, select that the product is digital and then when user's purchase it, a link to download the file will either be emailed to their email inbox or it will display on the screen. This link uses a randomly generated hash so other users won't be able to access it unless they know the hash. Also, the link expires after a certain amount of days so if they don't download the product in, say, a week they have to generate a new link. I believe also, once the link is accessed and the file is downloaded, the link expires as well so that others may not reuse the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Magento. It's most popular php-based e-commerce platform with a lot of extensions for any ideas.